# How i can using web view and one View inside ScrollView @shoutem/ui

Tags: react-native, shoutem

i try to use @shoutem/ui in my project!
i have one Component with Webview and one View inside!
I want design it like: Webview full screen, when scroll to end WebView i want see View, then i try to used ScrollView then put WebView and View inside, here is my code:

```js
  <ScrollView >
          <Screen styleName="paper">
            <WebView
              style={{
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                flex: 1,
              }}
              ref="myWebView"
              renderLoading={this.renderLoading}
              source={{ uri: this.state.rowdata.urlView }}
            />
          </Screen>

          <View styleName="horizontal space-between h-center" >
            <Button>
              <Icon name="like" />
            </Button>
            <TextInput
              placeholder={'Enter comment..'}
            />
            <Button>
              <Icon name="activity" />
            </Button>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
```

But i think i wend wrong in some where! Here is my result:
[image]

Please help me fix this! Thanks guys so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView automatically resizes itself, which means it'll shrink
itself to nothingness if put inside a ScrollView component.
WebView will show up fine if you give it a specific size:

```
  <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <WebView source={src} style={{height: 250}}/>
  </ScrollView>
```

You can find out a more detailed explanation of how ScrollView child
components work [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4773#issuecomment-198738602%201%20Comment).

Comment: if we have variable height for webview how to do it ?

Comment: @AlainIb were you able figure out what to do when webview has a variable height? facing similar issue.

Comment: @setshaft i ended removing scrollview,   // flex:1  style dont work for webview ! 

https://pastebin.com/Aie4eCuu

Comment: If you know the height of the webview, it's easy. Also give a height greater than the webview to ScrollView instead of flex property.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works as long as you can get height of webview before loading

```
<ScrollView style={{ height:1000}}>
        <WebView
        style={ { height:700} }
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
        
            source={{uri:"https://www.facebook.com" }}
            scrollEnabled={false}
        />
        <WebView
        style={ { height:700} }
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
        
            source={{uri:"https://www.facebook.com" }}
            scrollEnabled={false}
        />
        <View/>
                                    }
                                />
    </ScrollView>
```